# How can I send messages to my queue and a post request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a function that posts data to the database. It works fine but I would also like to use the same function to send a message to trigger another function.

I have tried to simultaneouslysend the message and make the post request but at this moment only the post request works

Here is what my code looks like

```
const params = {
    "TableName": "sites",
    "Item": {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      siteId: siteIdFinal,
      ...data,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    }
  };

  const messageParams = {
    MessageBody: 'Waddup fam',
    QueueUrl: ' https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/106845550704/MyQueue'
  };


  try {
    await dynamoDbLib.call("put", params);
    sqs.sendMessage(messageParams, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success: "+data.MessageId);
      }
    });

    return success(params.Item);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return failure({ status: false });
  }
```

I am not getting any error I am just getting returned back the data that has been posted. I thought i should receive the message Id of the message I sent but I am not getting that. When ever I look at the cloudwatch logs, the message isnt sent

Answer (score 0):

Your async function returns `params.Item` before sendMessage executes a callback.
Use a promise to make sure that both methods finish properly

```
await sqs.sendMessage(messageParams).promise()
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("Success: "+data.MessageId);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error: "+err);
  });
```

More on aws-sdk and promises:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/